# Problem with block devices for virtual machines

Tags: qemu, block-device, libvirt

I have two block devices in my host that I am trying to pass to a VM guest. One works perfectly while the other does not. The only difference is one is a logical volume on an internal drive while the other is a logical volume on a software RAID built on external thunderbolt drives. I am curious if I need to do a better job of making sure the partition tables are where the host and guest need them to be.

Both the guest and the host are running up to date Arch Linux. The first device in the host is on a logical volume on an LVM volume group on `/dev/nvme0n1p3` which is connected directly to the Intel NUC13 motherboard

```
# fdisk -l /dev/HomeServerNUC13VM/HomeServerNUC13Storage 
Disk /dev/HomeServerNUC13VM/HomeServerNUC13Storage: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CAEF53EA-821B-4A57-9FFB-E62CE5174E16

Device                                           Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/HomeServerNUC13VM/HomeServerNUC13Storage1    2048  2099199  2097152   1G EFI System
/dev/HomeServerNUC13VM/HomeServerNUC13Storage2 2099200 33552383 31453184  15G Linux filesystem
```

The second is a logical volume on a different LVM volume group on `/dev/md127p1` which is a software RAID 5 array on `/dev/nvme{1,2,3,4}n1p1`. All of these physical drives are in an external case and connected to the NUC via thunderbolt

```
# fdisk -l /dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage 
Disk /dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage: 2 TiB, 2199023255552 bytes, 536870912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DBF9C573-63AF-417B-ADE6-F6560D0702D9

Device                                      Start       End   Sectors Size Type
/dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage1   256 536870655 536870400   2T Linux filesystem
```

I can access the partitions on both block devices in the host with `kpartx -a` and mount them without issues. The problems come about when I pass the devices to the VM guest with

```
   <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
      <source dev='/dev/HomeServerNUC13VM/HomeServerNUC13Storage'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
      <source dev='/dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='sata'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
```

In the guest `/dev/HomeServerNUC13VM` shows up as `/dev/sda` and works fine, and while `/dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage` shows up as `/dev/sdb` it is screwed up. Note that the `Disklabel type` is `dos`

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT PMBR size mismatch (536870911 != 4294967295) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sdb: 2 TiB, 2199023255552 bytes, 4294967296 sectors
Disk model: QEMU HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT
```

If I recreate the partition table and partitions in the guest, then everything is fine in the guest

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 2 TiB, 2199023255552 bytes, 4294967296 sectors
Disk model: QEMU HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 00B06790-6D3B-4694-B435-6E9E6E9E12CB

Device     Start        End    Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 4294965247 4294963200   2T Linux filesystem
```

but back in the host things get screwed up. Again the `Disklabel type` is `dos`.

```
# fdisk -l /dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage 
Disk /dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage: 2 TiB, 2199023255552 bytes, 536870912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device                                      Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Storage1          1 4294967295 4294967295  16T ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I deleted the RAID 5 and recreated it directly on `/dev/nvme{1,2,3,4}n1` while putting the LVM directly on `/dev/md127` (i.e., without the partitions) and then made the LV 256 GB and still had the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in [the libvirt documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#hard-drives-floppy-disks-cdroms), specifically in the line:

```
blockio logical_block_size='512' physical_block_size='4096'
discard_granularity='4096'
```

QEMU has an option for that too; something like:

```
-device scsi-hd,bus=scsi1.0,drive=drive-virtio-disk1,id=virtio-scsi-pci1,physical_block_size=4096,logical_block_size=512
```

Answer (score 0):

The things I missed is the `/dev/nvme0n1` in the host has

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

while `/dev/nvme{1,2,3,4}n1` in the host has

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

In the guest the problematic device shows up with

```
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I think this mismatch in the sector size screws up the partition tables. It does not appear you can set the sector size for a virtual sata device, but you can with the blockio parameter of a virtio device

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native' discard='unmap'/>
  <source dev='/dev/HomeStorageOWC/HomeServerNUC13Web'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <blockio logical_block_size='4096' physical_block_size='4096'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```